# EditorJS Setup Image Block with Wordpress

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, wordpress, editorjs

I'm coding a blog site with Wordpress and I want to use EditorJS as editor. I know there is a plugin for this, but I want to install this editor without plugins.
I can save the written content to the database now and I can edit the previously saved or shared articles, but I cannot add/upload images. **How do I upload and use images from the EditorJS Image Block to Wordpress?**

[I put the block I was talking about here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x7BJG.png)

```
image: {
class: ImageTool,
config: {
  endpoints: {
    byFile: "http://localhost:8008/uploadFile", // Your backend file uploader endpoint
    byUrl: "http://localhost:8008/fetchUrl", // Your endpoint that provides uploading by Url
  },
},
```

},

thanks in advance